# Couldn't install Ad-Hoc in iPhone 3.0 OS?

Tags: iphone

I've created an Ad-Hoc of my iphone app, but i couldnt install it on my iPhone (upgraded to iPhone OS 3.0). And also i created new provisioning file and plist file but it still shows error:

**The application was not installed on th iPhone "Unknown" because an unknown error occured (0xE8008017)**

Please send me a solution..........

Comment: You did enter the correct Bundle Identifier in the plist right? And you also installed the Provisioning Profile for that App ID on the phone (Settings > General > Profiles)?

Have you tried restarting the phone?

Comment: I think the usual instructions involve building clean, closing and re-opening Xcode, standing up and walking around your chair three times clockwise and then five times counter-clockwise and then rebooting the phone.

Answer (score 2):

I saw the 0xE8008017 when dragging a .ipa file that I created into iTunes, but NOT when dragging the .app folder directly into iTunes.

Update: There seem to be lots of reasons why this can occur:

1) You should use "ditto" instead of "zip" to create the .ipa file, as that is what gets used if you use Finder and choose "Compress":

```
ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc Folder OutputFile.ipa
```

2) [This link](http://www.idotcom.us/2009/05/how-to-build-a-ipa-file-from-xcode/) has a comment explaining the error is due to stale resources, i.e. you have a file in the .app bundle that has not been code signed.  Check that all the files in your binary have a corresponding entry in the CodeResources file (except those explicitly excluded in ResourceRules.plist).

If you are trying to debug this problem you should check if dragging the .app folder into iTunes directly works.  If it does, look for a problem with your creation of the .ipa file.

On another occasion when I changed my Info.plist 'Bundle identifier' from com.domain.appname to appid.com.domain.appname it made iTunes report a 0xE8008019 error instead of the 0xE8008017 one (importing the .app still worked directly).  I think using appid.com.domain.appname in the Info.plist is wrong, but I mention it here in case somebody is searching for that error code!

Answer (score 0):

I solved one 0xE8008017 error by renaming one of my resources. It was a PNG file with the danish letter 'ø' in it.

I've seen one other report about 0xE8008017 where the fix was about a colon in one of the resource filenames.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error.
I looked for the names of the files in the resources.
But the names have only alphabets a-z and digits 1-9.
Only at couple of places, hyphen - and underscore _ have been used.
I don't think that can cause the issue.
What else can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic error, and often the real error will be reported to the OS X console.

Fire up the Console app (should be in Applications, or use Spotlight to find it automatically), and scroll to the bottom. Look at the timestamps, and see if there's a detailed message.

I've several times used this to fix *completely different* bugs which use the same error message.

(sadly, Apple is very bad at writing error messages - you often find they didn't bother to write new text for the popup error, and re-use old text, so that you have to read the Console to find out the "real" error)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer (I had this problem recently):

"Upgrade to iTunes 9"

A bunch of these "missing" error messages appear to have been added in iTunes v9, including some of the most common ones. I guess Apple just forgot to include them first time around...